# How to handle scrollview gestures inside a Flutter PageView?

Tags: flutter, scrollview, gesture, flutter-pageview

1. Summary of my problem

**Goal**

My goal is to present a carousel with long pages.
So I use a PageView with scrollviews.
The PageView scrolls horizontally.
The scrollviews (children) scroll vertically.

**Expected Results**

Swipe horizontally and scroll vertically smoothly.

**Actual Results**

If I swipe horizontally to the next page, I can't scroll it vertically right away.
I need to wait for 1 second.
It seems the user must wait the animation completion to be able to interact with the new current page.

**What have I tried so far :**

- I tried gesture recognizer to pass the dragging event but I didn't get it working.
- I tried different widgets to replace the PageView but same effect.
- I tried AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin with wantKeepAlive = true
- I tried PageView.physics = AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()

**Here's the minimum code you would need to reproduce the problem**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: carousel(),
    );
  }

  Widget carousel() {
    return PageView(
      children: <Widget>[
        page(Colors.pinkAccent),
        page(Colors.blueAccent),
        page(Colors.orangeAccent)
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget page(Color color) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color,
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
              children: pageContent()),
        ));
  }

  List<Widget> pageContent() {
    return <Widget>[
      Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Hop", textScaleFactor: 5,)]),
      Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Hop", textScaleFactor: 5,)]),
      Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Hop", textScaleFactor: 5,)]),
      Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Hop", textScaleFactor: 5,)]),
      Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Hop", textScaleFactor: 5,)]),
      Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Hop", textScaleFactor: 5,)]),
      Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Hop", textScaleFactor: 5,)]),
      Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Hop", textScaleFactor: 5,)]),
      Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Hop", textScaleFactor: 5,)]),
      Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Hop", textScaleFactor: 5,)]),
      Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Hop", textScaleFactor: 5,)]),
      Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Hop", textScaleFactor: 5,)]),
      Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Hop", textScaleFactor: 5,)]),
      Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Hop", textScaleFactor: 5,)]),
      Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Hop", textScaleFactor: 5,)]),
      Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Hop", textScaleFactor: 5,)]),
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded to find a solution to make my PageView really smooth horizontally and vertically.

I disable PageView.pageSnapping to make the carousel very smooth.
However I lost the magnetic effect, so I use a NotificationListener to catch the ScrollEndNotification event.
When the scrolling ends, I calculate the most visible page to the user and call PageController.animateToPage() to finish the job.

The code looks like this:

```
Widget getCarousel() {

  return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (scrollNotification) {

    if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
      print("ScrollEndNotification");

      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 0), () {
        int newPage = pageController.page.round();
        print("end at $newPage");
        pageController.animateToPage(newPage, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
      });
    }
    return true;
  },
  child: PageView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    pageSnapping: false,
    controller: pageController,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return myPages[index];
    },
  )
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little digging, I believe the issue lies in the DragStartBehavior of PageView. Intending to be smooth, the default behavior of PageView ends up feeling sluggish, the page snap almost feels like it had one too many drinks.

This means that while you want to vertical scroll, the PageView is still slurring through a change.

Adjust the DragStartBehavior when you call PageView and it will feel much more reactive - it will feel a little more snappy, which I believe may resolve your issue.

```
Widget carousel() {
    return PageView(
      children: <Widget>[
        dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
        page(Colors.pinkAccent),
        page(Colors.blueAccent),
        page(Colors.orangeAccent)
      ],
    );
  }
```

p.s Thank you Yunnosch for the reprimand and laugh :) Feel free to edit this out also since I cant exactly comment yet!

Comment: Even if you quote the rule you are breaking it still applies to you. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead So if you really think that what you are posting is not an answer, then DON'T. Please take the [tour] to understand better. But luckily for you I have seen worse answers who actually tried than what you consider a comment.... Especially, though your answer is largely link, you did add enough non-link details to just pass my treshold for link-only answers, which are also not considered appropriate here....

Comment: Better study [answer] before next you post a quasi-comment non-answer and get less lucky. Otherwise welcome to StackOverflow and have fun.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However it doesn't help to make my carousel smooth.
(PS: there is a typo in your example, the "dragStartBehavior" should be in PageView constructor).